# Spring mvc mapping json to pojo properties are null

Tags: java, json, spring, spring-mvc, jackson

A Rest service is mapped on one url with some @RequestBody where i am mapping json to pojo. Pojo contains nested classes following is sample code.

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/saveExampleObject.html", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public @ResponseBody List<String> saveExampleObjectDefintion(@RequestBody ExampleObject exampleObject) throws DataAccessException,DataNotPersistException {
    List<String> msg = saveService.save(exampleObject);
    return msg;
}
```

and the object is like

```
class ExampleObject{
String name;
SubClass subClass;
.....
}
```

and json is

```
{
"name":"name",
"subClass":{
.....
}
```

I have configured spring mvc annotation and conversion is also happening.
But **some fields are null**. I cross checked names of null field they are same as in json and pojo.

**P.S. Only first fields are getting values in subclass.Thanks.**

Comment: Did you see if the setters are fine ?

Comment: @PritamBanerjee thanks for quick response. Yes setters are fine.

Comment: Does the answer solve your problem ?

Comment: Nooo, setters were already fine.

Comment: Did you try and covert the exampleObject to POJO and see if all the values are correct ?

Comment: @PritamBanerjee thanks it was problem with setters only , I used some json parameters (correspondingly pojo variables) starting two letters as caps due to which those properties not mapped.

Comment: Cool. I added it as the answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here the setters were not defined properly and hence there was an error. Spring MVC uses the setters to properly convert POJO to JSON and vice versa.

Answer (score 2):

in your json you have subClass but in your class you have subclass... is case sensitive

Comment: sorry for typo, actually subclass is mapping but only first variable is getting value all others are null.

Comment: so you post subClass but only first property have a value...may you show me complete json and complete class.....